# How do we obtain an estimate for $\textbf{P}(X\geq 1)$ where $X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$?

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

Consider a simple sample $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ whose distribution is given by $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$.

(a) Determine an estimator for $\lambda$ according to the method of moments.

(b) Determine another estimator for $\lambda$ different from the previous one.

(c) Determine an estimate of $\textbf{P}(X\geq 1)$ in accordance to the method of moments.

**MY ATTEMPT**

As to the first case, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\lambda} = \textbf{E}(X) \Rightarrow \hat{\lambda} = \frac{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}}
\end{align*}

As to the second case, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}} = \textbf{Var}(X) = \textbf{E}(X^{2}) - \textbf{E}(X)^{2} \Rightarrow \hat{\lambda} = \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X^{2}_{k} - \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\right)^{2}\right]^{-1/2}
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

In the third case, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X\geq 1) = 1 - \textbf{P}(X < 1) = 1 - \exp(-1\times\lambda) = 1 - \exp(-\lambda)
\end{align*}

Now it suffices to substitute $\lambda$ for any of the above expressions.

Could someone double-check my reasoning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exponential distribution is continuous, but you're treating it as discrete.... is there a typo?

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I was thinking about the poisson distribution when I wrote it. Thanks for the observation. I will edit it.

Comment: What have you tried?  You know, don't you, that this is not a site for us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Plug the estimator in $(a)$ into $e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: Sorry, David. I know it. I just forgot to mention my attempts.

Comment: Check the expression for $\mathbf P(X\geq 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, NCh. I was missing a constant.

Comment: @user1337 This is not right.  $\lambda e^\lambda > 1$ for sufficiently large $\lambda$, so your probabililty is negative. Note that sign correction will not help. Look at CDF of exponential distribution.

Comment: So I was right . . .

Comment: @user1337 $1-e^\lambda<0$ for $\lambda>0$. This is not a probability!

Comment: Hmmm . . . I guess I was missing a minus sign then . . .